# Python - Sorting List of Ints User Input

Tags: python, input

I am having an issue with my input method, I am trying to get a list of ints seperated by spaces. My code is below:

```
def numberStore():
    numberList = input("Enter list of numbers seperated by spaces ").split(" ")
    print("The lowest number is" , listLowestNumber(numberList))
```

I then have a function to return the lowest number of the list that has been input.

```
def listLowestNumber(list):
    list.sort()
    return list[0]
```

However when I execute the function numberStore, it only seems to sort the numbers by the first digit, for example entering the values 40 9 50 will return a value of 40 as the lowest number. Thanks for any help!

Comment: `min(the_list, key=int)` is what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sort a list of integers represented as strings, one could use:

```
l.sort(key=int)
```

Without the `key=int`, the list gets ordered [lexicographically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

However, if all you need to do is find the smallest number, the better way is

```
return min(l, key=int)
```

P.S. I've renamed your list to `l` since `list()` is a [built-in name](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html), and it's poor style to shadow built-in names.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert values on your list to int before you sort them:

```
numberList = input("Enter list of numbers seperated by spaces ").split()
numberList = [int(v) for v in numberList]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's sorting by treating the elements as strings. What you describe is lexicographic ordering, not numerical ordering. Basically you have to convert your string elements into numerical elements.